# Can I modify a shared library file to work fine with my executable

Tags: c, shared-libraries

I have shared library file say `abc.so` that is made using say (`a.c`, `b.c`, `c.c`) files.
Now I have made by executable say `target.out`

My doubt is ... can i delete `abc.so` and separately again build `abc.so` from (`a.c`, `b.c`, `c.c`) and paste it wherever my previous `abc.so` was present.
However my `target.out` is the older one.

Now if i run `target.out` will it work fine with the new `abc.so` ??

Comment: if you don't change the interface (prototypes, types, ...), it should work.

Comment: It should work fine..

Comment: As well as saving space, this is part of the whole point of having dynamically loaded libraries, that you can update them without having to relink the programs that use them.

Comment: It depends on how other programs link with yours. If it's done dynamically and uses the export table (by name), then you'll be fine. Watch our for consumers that hardcode addresses or use export table indexes instead of names.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will work, but you must be careful.

Let's take as example libtest.c:

```
int my_global_var = 42;

int sum(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

It can be built with:

```
gcc -fPIC -shared -o libtest.so libtest.c
```

With `readelf -s libtest.so` we can see that the function and the global variable were exposed as public symbols :

```
$ readelf -s libtest.so
42: 0000000000200950     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   21 my_global_var
...
47: 0000000000000665    42 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 sum
...
```

It's important to notice that the `.so` file doesn't specify the types or the prototype of these symbols.

Now let's write a program that uses the lib:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* provided by libtest */
int sum(int, int);
extern int my_global_var;

int main()
{
    printf("5 + 2 = %d and my_global_var = %d\n", sum(5, 2), my_global_var);

    return 0;
}
```

And build it:

```
gcc -L. -ltest -o program program.c
```

It works:

```
$ ./program 
5 + 2 = 7 and my_global_var = 42
```

We can see that `program` is dynamically linked to `libtest.so`:

```
$ ldd program
...
libtest.so (0x00007f1138c70000)
...
```

Once again the symbols `sum` and `my_global_var` are referenced in the program headers without type or prototype:

```
$ objdump --dynamic-reloc program 
DYNAMIC RELOCATION RECORDS
OFFSET           TYPE              VALUE 
0000000000600b00 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT  __gmon_start__
0000000000600b50 R_X86_64_COPY     my_global_var
0000000000600b20 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLOT  printf
0000000000600b28 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLOT  __libc_start_main
0000000000600b30 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLOT  __gmon_start__
0000000000600b38 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLOT  sum
```

So this is how it works, as long as the library file is present and it contains the symbols referenced by the program, the dynamic linker is happy and writes the addresses of those symbols into a special indirection table inside the program's memory.

If we change `my_global_var` to 43, rebuild the lib, and run the program without rebuilding it:

```
$ ./program 
5 + 2 = 7 and my_global_var = 43
```

If we remove `my_global_var` from the lib, the symbol vanishes, and the program can't start, because the dynamic linker isn't happy:

```
$ ./program 
./program: symbol lookup error: ./program: undefined symbol: my_global_var
```

Now the tricky part, let's try to change the `sum`'s prototype:

```
int my_global_var = 43;

float sum(float a, float b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

We rebuild the library, and run the program:

```
$ ./program 
5 + 2 = 791621423 and my_global_var = 43
```

The dynamic linker doesn't complain, but the result is garbage as the program passed `int`s to a function that expected `float`s.

To sum up: it works as long as the types and the prototypes remain absolutely unchanged. If they change, the linker won't complain and weird things will start to happen.

To solve the last problem, big libraries use symbol versionning. It is a pretty complex subject, here is a detailed article about it: http://www.trevorpounds.com/blog/?p=33